Scrolling of nested DIV issue
The content loaded in the router outlet simply won't scroll
Here is the HTML
  <!-- Modal Container -->
    <div class="main-modal">

      <!-- Modal Sidebar -->
      <div class="modal-sidebar">

        <app-contract-sidebar/>

      </div>

      <!-- Modal Main -->
      <div class="modal-main">

        <!-- Router outlet for tab content -->
        <router-outlet></router-outlet>

      </div>

    </div>

Here are the CSS
/* modal main styles */
.main-modal {
  display: flex;
  padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
}

.modal-sidebar {
  width: var(--modal-sidebar-container-width);
  background-color: var(--modal-siderbar-background-color);
  padding: 6px 10px 6px 10px;
}

.modal-main {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-grow: 1;
  position: relative;
  padding: 4px 4px 4px 4px;
  background-color:  var(--modal-body-background-color);
  height: 100%;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

Modal Side Bar is not very long
The content in Modal Main is very long (but currently gets cut off)
This child component  is loaded from a parent component here:
    <div role="document" class="main-modal" (click)="stopPropogation($event)" >
       <div class="modal-body">
          <app-child/>
       </div>
    </div>

With this styling
.modal-body {
  padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
}

.main-modal {
  flex-grow: 1;
  overflow: hidden;
  z-index: 2;
}

